# Access denied in S3 sync

Tags: palantir-foundry

We have an S3-Direct cloud-based Source set up and just added our first Sync. It's designed to pick up files within an S3 bucket, crawling through several subfolders.

When running the Sync, it fails at the 'Fetch data' stage with a 403 Access denied error.
We believe permissions have been configured correctly on the S3 side but we're not sure whether the access problem arises on the Foundry or on the S3 side.

Do we first need to allowlist the S3 URL on the Foundry side?
For the S3 side, would anyone be able to share a sample S3 permissions configuration?

[image]

Comment: Hi Benjamin, did you check that you have granted the minimum required permissions to your AWS IAM user as described in the docs? 
https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/source-types/amazon-s3/#s3-direct

Comment: The fact that you're getting an 'AccessDenied' error code and 403 response means the network connection is getting through to AWS S3, so the issue isn't with allowlisting the S3 URL. Given this, it's likely an IAM permissions issue. AWS has an article on troubleshooting these kinds of issues: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-troubleshoot-403/